# No provider for HttpClient Karma/Jasmine Testing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Having this simples `.spec.ts` file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { UsersViewComponent } from './users-view.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/forms';
import { MyDateRangePickerModule } from '../../../node_modules/mydaterangepicker';
import { NgxEchartsModule, NgxEchartsService } from '../../../node_modules/ngx-echarts';
import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';
import { SessionService } from '../Services/session.service';
import { SortingService } from '../sorting.service';

describe('UsersViewComponent', () => {
  let component: UsersViewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UsersViewComponent>;



  beforeEach(async(() => {

    // Create a fake TwainService object with a `getQuote()` spy
    const sessionService = jasmine.createSpyObj('sessionService', ['getSessions']);
    // Make the spy return a synchronous Observable with the test data
    var getSessionSpy = sessionService.getSessions.and.returnValue(Observable.of({}));;


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MyDateRangePickerModule, NgxEchartsModule],
      declarations: [UsersViewComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: NgxEchartsService },
        { provide: SessionService, useValue: sessionService },
        { provide: SortingService }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UsersViewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And testing the component with the following constructor:

```
  constructor(private es: NgxEchartsService, private sessionService: SessionService, private sorting: SortingService) { }
```

Session Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Session } from '../models/Session';

@Injectable()
export class SessionService {

  sessionsURL = "http://localhost:8080/express/ux/sessions";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSessions(user: string, pageTitle: string, deviceType: string, browser: string, beginDate: number, endDate: number, os: string, screenRes: string,company:string): Observable<Session[]> {
    return this.http.get<Session[]>(this.sessionsURL + this.buildArguments(user, pageTitle, deviceType, browser, beginDate, endDate, os, screenRes,company));
  }
```

It gives me that error. The thing is that, if I add the HTTPClientModule to the spec imports, it correctly loads but the actual request in the service is made. It just bypassed the mock `getSessions` method.

Any clue, why this happens?

I have made a similiar approach in another component and it worked straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing with HttpClientModule there's a special module in Angular: The HttpClientTestingModule. This allows you to mock this the HttpClientModule without doing a real Http-Call. You have to import this Module to the test. Hope that helps.

Comment: That was exactly it. Solved!